# Bug with youtube embed when using css 'column-count'

Tags: css, google-chrome, youtube

I inserted a youtube embed code (the iframe code) in a webpage, and used css column-count to automatically divide text in the page to two columns.

```
.newspaper
{
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
}
```

The problem is when i embed youtube video after the initial viewport it is shown as black image. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KTvCV/689/. Seems this is bug with youtube and chrome. Is there any solution/fix for this issue? 
Tried different things and not working so thinking to go with jQuery columnizer instead of CSS column count.

Comment: I have the same problem, not only with Chrome, but also with Safari. Safari seems to move the iframe below the columns, if it is the last part of the content. And sometimes renders / sometimes not. Firefox seems to render without problems.

Comment: As this is an issue for me, and I couldn't find any other tips or solution about it, in addition to above, I also have a problem in Safari. If the left column content is smaller than the height of the iframe, the iframe visuals jump down below the columns (only the visuals, NOT the actual content: you can still click on the video where it was located). see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KTvCV/726/

Comment: If you don't mind so much about performance and using some JS hack, I managed to trigger correct positioning by setting a style attribute to the iframe. E.g. Set its width to its current width through Javascript, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnds97m2/

Answer (score 2):

### Trouble Replicating This Problem - Observations

I am seeing very inconsistent behavior with Chrome trying to display iframe embedded videos in a multi-column format.

The following did not seem to clear the problem consistently:

1. I tried putting `<p>` tags around the text thinking it might be line
   length related quirk.
2. I tried clearing the cache.
3. Changing the width of the column
4. Changing the dimensions of the iframe

In addition, videos below the fold seem not to be rendered (painted?).

### Once Case That Works

The only situation that seems to render well is having a single video that appearing in the first column.

I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: i can confirm the same thing. The video only worked when on first column. I tried adding z-index and I could see the video but wasn't clickable to play.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, for me the fix was to give the `<iframe>` an explicit `width` in pixels, `position: relative`, `z-index`, and a 3d-transform such as `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`.

Experienced in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) for OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Seems like you just need a `width` in pixels. Unfortunately still doesn't let me combine responsive embeds with columns.

Comment: Adding the transform worked for me - but then Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit) came along and fixed it as well - just when I had found this answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, only adding `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` on my `<video>` tag worked.

Note: I use a `<video>` tag, not an embedded `<iframe>` YouTube video. But I had the same problem with columns.

Comment: Worked for me too. Found your answer on the same day that I update to Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit) which also fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the issue with having a YouTube video combined with column-count. http://codepen.io/djschoone/pen/VYdaOv shows what's happening. The video moves to an other position.

HTML

```
<html>
 <body>
   <article class="display-2col">
   <p>Text</p>
   <p><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GUstB3VS4KY?rel=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="614"     height="370" class="video-filter video-youtube vf-gustb3vs4ky" frameborder="0">    </iframe></p>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.display-2col{
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -moz-column-gap:20px;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-gap:20px;
  column-count:2;
  column-gap:20px;
}
```

The difference with IE and FF is the video is placed with the  tag on Chrome whilst the others get the  tag served.

I guess it has something to do with positioning. Looking into it!

Comment: So are you answering, saying that the issue exists? While this might be valuable information, I doubt it fits into the SO "answer" category.