# iframes escaping css columns in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I am trying to set up Iframes inside a grid with 3 columns.

---

### HTML

```
<div id="blogPosts">

    <div class="blogPost">
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YqeW9_5kURI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <div class="title">Youtube Video</div>
        <div class="time">11th May, 2015</div>
        <div class="info">this is the best youtube video ever!</div>
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#blogPosts {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.blogPost {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

## What it is like:

[image]

---

## What I want it to be like:

[image]

---

But the problem is, is that the iframe jumps out of the grid. Here is [my JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygw1qbzc/) to show you it happening. As you can see the first 'box' works fine (as expected) but the next two boxes to the right, the iframe escapes?

Comment: Do you need to use the column property or could you use another solution to the problem?

Comment: I think I need the column property it is so close to what I actually want, it is just the iframe running away... So strange!!

Comment: I can’t really see anything wrong with any of the videos, using Firefox 37. What do you mean by “the iframe escapes”? What exactly happens and what do you expect to happen? And what browser are you using?

Comment: @Xufox have you seen the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Xufox please see added images above

Comment: Yep, that’s what I thought… what browser are you using? Chrome 42? It looks perfectly fine on Firefox 37.

Comment: Chrome!! it is weird because I adjusted the width on jsfiddle slightly and that is how I got the **"What I want it to be like"** (AKA it worked) but I have changed the width on the chrome browser and it doesn't change!

Comment: tested on Safari and works perfectly! (and all this time I thought Chrome was god)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding:

```
iframe{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Solved my problem with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27200299/2768038) !

Comment: if iframe already has transform and this is still occurring, using it on the parent fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Modified your code by adding position to the blogpost Class.

```css
#blogPosts {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;

}
.blogPost {
      display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 32.1%;
  position: absolute;
}

.blogPost:nth-child(1){
left: 34.2%;
}
.blogPost:nth-child(2){
left: 67.1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="blogPosts">
    <div class="blogPost">
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YqeW9_5kURI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <div class="title">Youtube Video</div>
        <div class="time">11th May, 2015</div>
        <div class="info">this is the best youtube video ever!</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="blogPost">
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YqeW9_5kURI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <div class="title">Youtube Video</div>
        <div class="time">11th May, 2015</div>
        <div class="info">this is the best youtube video ever!</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="blogPost">
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YqeW9_5kURI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <div class="title">Youtube Video</div>
        <div class="time">11th May, 2015</div>
        <div class="info">this is the best youtube video ever!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Will this solve your problem?

Comment: Why are the widths pretty random percentages? How did you come up with them?

Comment: I added the same code in [https://jsfiddle.net/4ejrd6g2/] Its working. Actually the width and left value you can equalize and add.

Comment: I have added a few more posts and look what [happens](https://jsfiddle.net/4ejrd6g2/2/)

Comment: Refer this post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808185/bug-with-youtube-embed-when-using-css-column-count). My suggestion is ... its a known issue around Youtube and chrome. You have to go with other approach. by controlling through width instead of column count in CSS